# Flutter, TextField direction line by line

Tags: flutter

how i can build a textField to change text direction line by line ( based on the first character )

For example, I want it to be displayed as below when typing 2 letters in different languages in the text field

```
// this line started with LTR characters, start at left
Hi Good morning

// this line started with RTL characters, start at right
                 سلام، صبح بخیر

Are you ok?
                    حالت خوبه؟
```

I looked at Flutter's code and noticed that Flutter uses text span to create text in the text field (that is, all the text can only be changed), is this possible with Flutter's own text field widget?

Comment: This may help you https://pub.dev/packages/auto_direction

Comment: @AhmadRaza ``` textDirection: isRTL(text) ? TextDirection.rtl : TextDirection.ltr,``` this package change all text to rtl or ltr i want change line by line :)

Comment: Can you please share code what you had tried so far